# lock column and stay responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Lets says that I have page with 2 column:

thin column that contain many results. clicking on each result will show it on the other, bigger, column.

It's looks like in here:

https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/intel-jobs-SRCH_KE0,5_IP2.htm

```
<section class="col-md-4">
   results
</section>

<section class="col-md-8">
   content
</section>
```

how do I lock one of the column and still keep the site responsive?

In the example the right column is always on the top. even when you scroll down.

I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: Suggest you study some responsive layout and css media query tutorials. Question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are only instructing bootstrap to display column 4 and 8 in md.
Try to use xs to get the desired output.

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
   results
</div>

<div class="col-xs-8">
   content
</div>
```